# Paypal chargebacks

Tags: internet, international

I hope this is the right place to ask this kind of question!
I am a videogame streamer on twitch.tv. It is pretty common to have a so called donation button there. It is a button where you can support your streamer with a little tip so he can buy a beer or the next cool game with it. The method which is used the most for those transactions is Paypal. In Paypal you can make chargebacks as a "buyer" (the donator) and the "seller" (the streamer) has to refund the money and has to pay refund fee to Paypal. Since there are people who think it is funny to donate you 1000€ and then chargeback the money so you have to pay back a fee you have to make a proper statement on your page to obviously display the situation so you have a higher probability of winning the dispute that might follow, because obviously you don't want to support this fraud behaviour. On my donation page I have the following statement at the moment

> You don't purchase any kind of product or service with this payment.
>   With this transaction you donate to my stream to support it. Donations
>   are non-refundable! If there are any questions regarding the donation,
>   please feel free to contact me at my@email.com

Is this actually enough to protect myself from chargebacks and defend myself later on from people who want to get their money back?

I am sorry for my bad English, it is not my native language!

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: how much the PayPal refund fee?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may help you defend yourself, it will not prevent the problem.

Section 4.3 of the PayPal User Agreement indicates that you agree to be responsible for all chargebacks and fees. You cannot get out of that agreement with PayPal by passing on your liability to a third party, which is essentially what your disclaimer attempts to do.

Your best bet, and in fact the only way you can protect yourself, is to refund large amounts as soon as they hit your account.